# React component doesn't render when I change its state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a clock feature on my React site, and I have written this code for the component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Clock extends Component {
  state = { time: "00:00" };

  getTime = () => {
    var d = new Date();
    var hours = d.getHours();
    var mins = d.getMinutes();
    var secs = d.getSeconds();
    if (mins < 10) {
      mins = "0" + mins;
    }
    if (secs < 10) {
      secs = "0" + secs;
    }
    let formatDate = hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs;
    this.setState({ time: formatDate });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getTime();
    setInterval(this.getTime(), 1000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p className="Clock">{this.state.time}</p>
        <button onClick={this.getTime}>Refresh</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Clock;
```

I am trying to make the time that this component displays update every second, and I thought that just using `setState` would re-render it. I then found out that I could put the code in a method, and then call this method inside of a `setInterval` in `componentDidMount` however neither of these methods worked.

I am probably doing something dumb, but is there a simple way I can get this component to re-render itself every second?

Comment: `setInterval(this.getTime(), 1000);` -------------> `setInterval(this.getTime, 1000);`

Comment: @Yousaf wow, that worked perfectly, thanks. If you don't mind, could explain why that worked?

Comment: use TypeScript and you won't have this kind of errors anymore. https://www.typescriptlang.org/

Comment: first argument to `setInterval` should be a function that `setInterval` can call after specific interval. Instead of passing the function, you were calling the function

Comment: I suggest you clear the interval when the component will unmount. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 componentDidMount() {
  this.getTime();
  setInterval(this.getTime, 1000);
}
```